# Problema con caracter de escape ( \ ) en sentencia de sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, pragma

Tengo el método, **obtenerCampos**, perteneciente a una clase que da lugar a la conexión a una base de datos, contiene y ejecuta sentencias sqlite.
El problema que tengo es cuando quiero utilizar `PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO`, ya que si utilizo `print` la sentencia sale como quiero, que seria del siguiente modo:

`SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('nombre_tabla_x')`

Pero al asignar esta sentencia a la variable orden y colocarla dentro del método, el cual retornaría una lista con los nombres de las columnas de una determinada tabla, pasa lo siguiente:

`SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO( \ ' nombre_tabla_x \ ')`

El carácter `escape` sale como parte de la sentencia dando error, me podrían indicar como hacer para que no salga el carácter de escape en ( \ ) como parte de la sentencia?

```py
def obtenerCampos(self):
    tabla = self.devolverTabla()
    orden = 'SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO(\'' + tabla + '\')'
    lista = list(self.ejecutar(orden)
    
    return lista
```

Comment: Utiliza los 2 tipos de comillas, las comillas dobles `""` para declarar el string y las simples `''` para elaborar la consulta sql. Además puedes usar *f-strings* de esta forma  `f"SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO({tabla})"`

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar pero probe con este f-strings y me da error diciendo que no existe la columna y en el nombre de columna sale el nombre de la tabla porque lo que hace es esto SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO( nombre_tabla_x ), cuando deberia hacer esto SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO( ' nombre_tabla_x ' ), entre los parentesis y el nombre de la tabla tienen que aparecer comillas simples.

Comment: Pues ponle las comillas `f"SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('{tabla}')"`

Comment: @mag55 Python admite los dos tipo de comilla en una cadena: print("Hello world");` o `print('Hello World');` y te dá la ventaja de no usar caracteres de escape: `print("La letra 'a' es una vocal");`.

Comment: Hola, perdon por la demora, lo que me funcionó fue reeplazar, f"SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('{tabla}')" por f'SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO("{tabla}")', lo que me resulto curioso es que em el listado me incluye los campos 'id' que antes no lo hacia, saludos.